# How to keep the windows aspect ratio while resizing the window in SFML 2.5?

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to know if there is a way to keep the windows aspect ratio while resizing the window like when you scale a layer and pressing shift in photoshop.

[image: example of what I want]

Comment: My first thought is to listen for a [`sf::Event::Resized`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Event.php#af41fa9ed45c02449030699f671331d4aa67fd26d7e520bc6722db3ff47ef24941) event and then call [`sf::Window::setSize`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Window.php#ab94ea32f22d15c0df11588e319de2546) to enforce that the ratio is mantained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally manage to do what I wanted to do. I listen to [sf::Event::Resized](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Event.php#af41fa9ed45c02449030699f671331d4aa67fd26d7e520bc6722db3ff47ef24941) and calling [sf::Window::setSize](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Window.php#ab94ea32f22d15c0df11588e319de2546) then I adapted the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15417994/11525112) which look like that :

```cpp
// set screen size
float screenWidth = 800.f;
float screenHeight = 600.f;
// get the resized size
sf::Vector2u size = _window.getSize();
// setup my wanted aspect ratio
float  heightRatio = screenHeight / screenWidth;
float  widthRatio = screenWidth / screenHeight;
// adapt the resized window to my wanted aspect ratio
if (size.y * widthRatio <= size.x)
{
    size.x = size.y * widthRatio;
}
else if (size.x * heightRatio <= size.y)
{
    size.y = size.x * heightRatio;
}
// set the new size
_window.setSize(size);
```

Comment: Does it work "on the fly" while resizing with the mouse?

Comment: OK, I tried it and I can see it doesn't, even if updating continuously, outside of event-polling, in a separate thread. I guess that's the limitation of the platform.